# Cookies in microsoft web bot nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, session-cookies, botframework

I have a nodeJS Microsoft website chatbot and I want to add a feature to retain user conversation when a user closes the window and reopen. Can we use cookies in this case or is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Where is your bot hosted? On a website with WebChat? Because default generated code has provision for state management by using Azure Table Storage or Cosmos DB. So state is retained automatically, and conversation will resume for users, if they are on channels like facebook and skype. This will still not work in WebChat hosted on Web page (you mention that user closes the window and reopen), as each refresh of web page will create a new conversation. There are ways other ways though to retain conversatonID in WebChat too!

Answer (score 1):

There are options to [manage conversation state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state). This GitHub issue mentions that you can implement your own way to save state by implementing the [IStorageClient interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/IStorageClient.ts).

[This](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AzureSql#more-about-the-default-state-client) looks like an example of how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/615) for using storing past conversation history in WebChat, but it looks like it might be on hold for now. This concept is something we want to get into WebChat, but there are still some details to be hammered out.